# having trouble importing web3

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3.py, python, import

[image]

[image]

getting this import web3 error although pip install web3 was a successs

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely `not` using the same virtual environment for both -

1. Installing web3 lib via `pip install web3` and
2. Running your python code.

You can configure which python interpreter to use.

If I were in your shoes, I would follow these steps-

1. Create a new virtual environment for this file - `python3 -m venv .venv`
2. Set this as the virtual environment for the project
3. Install web3.py via `pip install web3`

And you would no longer have those issues

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ ?
It is necessary to install visual c ++ build tools

Comment: pip install web3 was a success, but then I don't understand why I am I getting this error then